# How to run a command after apt-get upgrade

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

Recently I came across the nice [`checkrestart`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/debian-goodies) tool, that checks if running processes use an outdated version of a recently updated library and would need a restart to load them with the updated lib. At the moment I have to call `checkrestart` by hand every time I have used `apt-get upgrade` or `aptitude upgrade`.

Is there a way to invoke such a command automatically after `apt-get` or `aptitude` have upgraded some packages? Bonus points if the solution also works with `unattended-upgrades`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some more searching it turned out what I already suspected: `apt` itself provides a set of hooks to invoke commands at certain events, which is used by a lot of tools but seems to be barely documented.

Calling a tool like `checkrestart` after a package upgrade is fairly simple. One hast just to put the following code line either into `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or one of the existing files or a new file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`:

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke-Success { '/usr/sbin/checkrestart';};
```

This will call `checkrestart` every time that `dpkg` was called by `apt` (and of course any other tool that relies on `apt`, such as `aptitude`) and finished successfully.

Comment: Keep in mind that `apt` often calls `dpkg` multiple times each time it is run.

Comment: [Where did you find `DPkg::Post-Invoke-Success`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/whats-the-difference-between-dpkgpost-invoke-and-dpkgpost-invoke-success) In the source code, I can only find `DPkg::Post-Invoke`, `APT::Update::Post-Invoke` and `APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

**Using a Script**

A quick and dirty solution would be to write a script called `apt-get` or `aptitude` and make it call the actual program as such:

```
#!/bin/bash
# filename: apt-get

# '$@' is all of the arguments passed to the script
/usr/bin/apt-get-bin "$@"
# or /usr/bin/aptitude-bin "$@"

if [[ $1 == *upgrade* ]] ; then
    checkrestart
fi
```

Make the script executable: `chmod +x apt-get`. You may also want to make the script owned by root: `chown root apt-get; chgrp root apt-get`. Be careful not to set the setuid bit on your script, because if an attacker gains write privileges to it, they could quickly and easily modify it to give them a root shell.

This method would of course require you to move the actual binary to another location and move your shell script to some location in your path. The proper place to put user scripts is `/usr/local/bin`. In this situation though, you should put your script in the location the actual binary was in before you moved it in order to keep things organized.

Replacing the binary with a script in this manner is fairly intrusive and affects all users on the machine. As an alternative, you could call your script something like `apt-get-cr` and just remember to call that script instead of `apt-get`. You could also write a shell function.

**Using a Shell Function**

Using a shell function allows you to keep the command name `apt-get` without having to move around binaries.

```
apt-get() {
    # 'command' makes sure this function doesn't call itself.
    # You could also use a direct path the binary as shown above.
    command apt-get "$@"

    if [[ $1 == *upgrade* ]] ; then
        checkrestart
    fi
}
```

Put this function somewhere in your shell configuration (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, etc.)

This method is generally a lot less intrusive than the script method. Also, it doesn't require moving around the binaries, which is generally something only the root user can do.

On the downside, the shell function method isn't always very portable between shells and doesn't inherently mesh well with graphical interfaces such as launcher bars in the way the script method does (you can almost always treat a script like an executable binary.)

Comment: You need to quote `$@` properly, your arguments will be mangled.

Comment: As you already introduced it in the initial version of your answer, it is some kind of a workaround. My hope was that apt or aptitude already provide some own mechanism or hook to execute such commands. I hope you don't take it amiss if I wait some days if there will come up some other answer.