# What's the difference between DPkg::post-invoke and DPkg::post-invoke-success?

Tags: apt, dpkg

There are two suggested configuration options to install post-install hooks into Debian's apt/dpkg system: `DPkg::post-invoke`[(1)](https://askubuntu.com/a/63744/77957) and `DPkg::post-invoke-success`[(2)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71079/21808).

For me, only `post-invoke` seems to work and I could not find any documentation about `post-invoke-success`.  Can someone enlighten me about differences, if they exist, and maybe which alternative should be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three different hooks called `Post-Invoke` or `Post-Invoke-Success`, all managed by the `apt` tools:

- `DPkg::Post-Invoke`, which is invoked after every execution of `dpkg` (by an `apt` tool, not manually);
- `APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success`, which is invoked after successful updates (*i.e.* package information updates, not upgrades);
- `APT::Update::Post-Invoke`, which is invoked after updates, successful or otherwise (after the previous hook in the former case).

These are handled respectively in [`apt-pkg/deb/dpkgpm.cc`, line 1509](http://sources.debian.net/src/apt/1.1.10/apt-pkg/deb/dpkgpm.cc/#L1509) and [`apt-pkg/update.cc`, lines 111](http://sources.debian.net/src/apt/1.1.10/apt-pkg/update.cc/#L111) and [114](http://sources.debian.net/src/apt/1.1.10/apt-pkg/update.cc/#L114). There is no `DPkg::Post-Invoke-Success` hook that I can find.

If you want to add a hook to all `dpkg` invocations, you should look at the `post-invoke` hook in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg`, which is equivalent to `DPkg::Post-Invoke` above but is applied in all cases, not just `apt`-based executions of `dpkg`. To see examples of all the `apt` configuration options, look at `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz`.

Comment: Example for the `dpkg` post-hook: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200057/44722